# Access video stream from Cloud IP Camera

Tags: ffmpeg, vlc

I have bought a new "cloud IP" camera and I don't know If I can access video stream over RTSP or some other protocol from local computer?

I would like to stream a video over VLC or FFMpeg program.

The model of camera is: CIPC-GC13H

[image]

thank you for any info

Answer (score 1):

Found here a solution about RTSP : https://ipcamtalk.com/threads/meisort-y203s.24661/

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks for posting this. Just in case this link goes down.

url: rtsp://192.168.1.3:8001/0/avN
username: admin
password:

***No password***